# PHP MySQL Search Doesn't Work?

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a simple MySQL query search in one of my PHP site, but it doesn't work as I expect. When user search a term in my search bar, if the content he/she looking for doesn't exist, my function should return 'no results'. but it just display blank, no message nothing.

Here is my code for the search:

```
function querySearch($searchTerm) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM content_en WHERE content_body LIKE '%{$searchTerm}%' ORDER BY id DESC ";
    return $query;  
}

function getSearch($searchTerm) {
    $queryContents= querySearch($searchTerm);
    $exeQuery = mysql_query($queryContents);
    while( $fetchSet = mysql_fetch_array($exeQuery) ){
        if(empty($fetchSet)){
            echo "No Results Found";
        }else{
            if(empty($fetchSet['content_title'])){
                echo 'Sorry No results Found';
            }else{
                echo '<h2><a href="index.php?pageId='.$fetchSet['id'].'">'.$fetchSet['content_title'].'</a></h2><br/>';
                echo '<div>'.shortText($fetchSet['content_body'], 220).'</div><br/><br/>';
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Just my forcing it to work , so that's why there are two check for fetchSet array one for whole array one for only one key. But yea it doesn't work.

Comment: Just a note, you should be using `mysqli_*` or `PDO` as `mysql_*` is deprecated.

Comment: @TimWithers You mean "discouraged", although I guess that's essentially the same thing

Comment: @Mike, you're correct.  That was an error on my part.  It's Monday...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because there is either an error in your query or it has returned no results.

First, you should add some sort of error handling to your `mysql_query`, like this:

```
$exeQuery = mysql_query($queryContents) or die(mysql_error());
```

Second, the reason it would never print anything out if no results are found is because `mysql_fetch_array` will only loop over the results if there is a result to obtain. Therefore, if 0 rows are returned, the whole `while` loop is skipped completely. Instead you can use `mysql_num_rows` **BEFORE** you loop.

For example:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($exeQuery) > 0) {
    while( $fetchSet = mysql_fetch_array($exeQuery) ){
        echo '<h2><a href="index.php?pageId='.$fetchSet['id'].'">'.$fetchSet['content_title'].'</a></h2><br/>';
        echo '<div>'.shortText($fetchSet['content_body'], 220).'</div><br/><br/>';
    }
}
else {
    echo "No Results Found";
}
```

Comment: I believe the first if block inside of the while loop is redundant. That should essentially be checked with the `mysql_num_rows($exeQuery)` so that shouldn't really ever happen in there (I think). Please do correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
function querySearch($searchTerm) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM content_en WHERE content_body LIKE '%{$searchTerm}%' ORDER BY id DESC ";
    return $query;  
}

function getSearch($searchTerm) {
    $queryContents = querySearch($searchTerm);
    $exeQuery = mysql_query($queryContents);
    if(mysql_num_rows($exeQuery) > 0)
    {
        while( $fetchSet = mysql_fetch_array($exeQuery) )
        {
            echo '<h2><a href="index.php?pageId='.$fetchSet['id'].'">'.$fetchSet['content_title'].'</a></h2><br/>';
            echo '<div>'.shortText($fetchSet['content_body'], 220).'</div><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
         echo "No Results Found";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but I do recall that `mysql_fetch_array` will work *only if* there are actual results fetched. The while loop will only run when the `mysql_fetch_array` function runs successfully. However, when the query returns no results, `mysql_fetch_array` will not run successfully, so the loop will not run, thus, your if block is not given the opportunity to run either.

Edit: Habeeb's code should fix your problem for you :p. Keeping my answer here though, since I do provide some explanation as to the problem with your code. I'm sure it will be a useful reference to someone who might look at this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try This one..

```
function querySearch($searchTerm) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM content_en WHERE content_body LIKE '%{$searchTerm}%' ORDER BY id DESC";
    return $query;  
}

function getSearch($searchTerm) {
    $queryContents= querySearch($searchTerm);
    $exeQuery = mysql_query($queryContents);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($exeQuery);
    if($num_rows)
    {
        while( $fetchSet = mysql_fetch_array($exeQuery) ){
            echo '<h2><a href="index.php?pageId='.$fetchSet['id'].'">'.$fetchSet['content_title'].'</a></h2><br/>';
            echo '<div>'.shortText($fetchSet['content_body'], 220).'</div><br/><br/>';
        }
    }else{
        echo "No Result Found!";
    }
}
```